# USB bootable verison of Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope)?

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, usb-boot

Does anyone know of a version of Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty Jackalope) that can be booted off a USB? Instructions on how to do same would also be of help.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

have you checked pendrivelinux.com or tried using unetbootin as recommended by the #1 ranked google search for "ubuntu usb boot 9.04" at http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/how-to-create-a-bootable-live-ubuntu-904-usb-drive/  ??